# Comparing element values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find an element in the ArrayList "minions" with the highest "evilLevel" (that's defined in another class).

```
public Minion(String name, int evilLevel, boolean onMission) - from class Minion


    private Set<Minion> minions;
    int maxEvilLevel = 0;
    Minion theMostEvilMinion;  

     public MinionRegister(){


        minions = new HashSet<Minion>();
      }

     public Minion getMostEvilMinion(){
        if(minions.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }


        for(Minion m : minions){
            if(m.getEvilLevel() > maxEvilLevel) {
                maxEvilLevel = m.getEvilLevel();
                Minion theMostEvilMinion = m;
            }
        }
        return theMostEvilMinion;
    }
```

Unfortunately the method returns "null"

Comment: This code won't compile. Please have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You _say_ `ArrayList`, but your code is using a `HashSet`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Oh, right, originally I think I was using ArrayList but then switched to HashSet and got slightly lost in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for(Minion m : minions){
    if(m.getEvilLevel() > maxEvilLevel) {
        maxEvilLevel = m.getEvilLevel();
        Minion theMostEvilMinion = m;
    }
}
return theMostEvilMinion;
```

Inside the `for` loop, you declaring and setting a local variable `theMostEvilMinion`, which is then forgotten, because it is declared inside that block.

Then after the loop, you return the instance variable `theMostEvilMinion`, a *different* variable which is declared at the top of your class.

You need to declare and set one local `theMostEvilMinion` variable and then return it.

```
Minion theMostEvilMinion = null;
int maxEvilLevel = 0;
for (Minion m : minions) {
    if (m.getEvilLevel() > maxEvilLevel) {
        maxEvilLevel = m.getEvilLevel();
        theMostEvilMinion = m;
    }
}
return theMostEvilMinion;
```

Then you can also delete the `theMostEvilMinion` and `maxEvilLevel` instance variables.